# How can i reload the page in gradio?

Tags: python, gradio

I am new to gradio and trying to make a web interface in python. I want to add a button which can restart the server and reload the page but failed.

I've tried the code:

```
import gradio as gr

class Processing(object):
    def __init__(self, ui_obj):
        self.ui_obj = ui_obj
      
    def create_ui(self):
        with self.ui_obj:
            gr.Markdown("""Test Web """)
            with gr.Tabs():
                with gr.TabItem("test"):
                            dropdown = gr.inputs.Dropdown(label = 'choose file', choices=os.listdir('data'))
                            select_file_action = gr.Button("confirm")
                            file_setup_result_label = gr.Label(self.select_result)

            

             restart_gradio = gr.Button()

                        
             restart_gradio.click(
                self.restart_ui,
                [],
               []
             )
            
            select_file_action.click(
                self.load_existed_index,
                [
                    dropdown
                ],
                [
                    file_setup_result_label    
                ]
)
    def launch_ui(self):
        self.ui_obj.launch(share=True,server_name = '0.0.0.0', server_port=8080)
    
    def restart_ui(self):
        self.ui_obj.stop()  # Stop the current instance
        self.ui_obj.clear()  # Clear the UI elements
        self.create_ui()  # Recreate the UI elements
        self.launch_ui()  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_app = gr.Blocks()
    gradio_ui = GPTProcessing(my_app)
    gradio_ui.create_ui()
    gradio_ui.launch_ui()
```

and got the error:

```
'Blocks' object has no attribute 'stop'
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
btn_refresh = gr.Button(value="Refresh the page")
btn_refresh.click(None, _js="window.location.reload()")
```

This is going to create a button and when it's clicked the page will get reloaded

Comment: Where does `run_js` come from?

Comment: @one Im sorry it should have been None, ive edited it

Comment: Maybe this method is outdated?

TypeError: EventListener._setup.<locals>.event_trigger() got an unexpected keyword argument '_js'

Comment: It seems like in recent versions the '_js' is changed to 'js'. I'm using the following to do something similar:
        search_button.click(
          fn = None
          , inputs=[search_type, search_term]
          , outputs=[]
          , js = """function change_page(search_type, search_term) { 
                        console.log(search_type + ' ' + search_term);
                        url_str = '/?search_type=' + search_type + '&search_term=' + search_term;
                        window.location.assign(url_str); 
                    }"""
        )